# With access to near-future technology, what is the largest amount of healthy children a mother could give birth to in her lifetime?

Tags: biology, near-future, population

Essentially for my story my Evil Empire needs a constant and huge amount of new population to conscript for their armies. The way they accomplish this is by forcing every female member of society (aside from those in the Upper Courts that is) to continuously produce children.

**With access to near-future technology, what is the largest amount of healthy children a mother could give birth to in her lifetime?**

This can include using any manner of IVF or other technologies, the only requirement is that the offspring survives the birth in a healthy enough state to be able to grow to adulthood and hold a gun.

Also, considering the fact this is an evil empire, **Ethics and Morals need not apply.**

Comment: Impossible to say & any answer is going to be primarily opinion based, what your really asking for is "what ways might we go about maximizing births" -- lifespan? a lifetime is a non specific period of time, so is that an average lifetime? & if yes would that be average biblical, average modern south coast US or seventeenth century Ugandan average lifetimes? question needs more detail.

Comment: "*to continuously produce children.*" Who's going to raise them?

Comment: It's simple math: 9 months of pregnancy + 2 months of recovery is 11 months.  The 31 (inclusive) years from 15 to 45 is 372 months, which is 34 pregnancies.

Comment: @RonJohn : not so simple, not everyone hits menopause at 45, not everyone lives too 45, not everyone hits puberty at 15 (the average is nearer 11 by the way), plus OP specifies "near-future tech" & no "Ethics and Morals". So we've option on using drugs to induce puberty early & more to delay menopause, possible options on inducing pregnancy a month or two early so you can impregnate them again sooner plus of course fertility drugs to increase the instances of multiple births (twins, triplets, etc). With the question as given any answer can only be completely opinion based.

Comment: So what I'm hearing is that I should change the question from "How many births are possible" to "What are some methods of increasing births." The issue I have with this option is that it changes the answer far beyond what I'm looking for. I'm also not entirely sure how this is too opinion based, as I would have believed a question like this relies only on reproductive science.

Comment: @Pelinore I voted-to-close Too Broad.  Yes, my comment is simplistic, but shows that the answer is nothing but grade school math.

Comment: "* would have believed a question like this relies only on reproductive science.*" Sydney, you're ignoring the question of who would raise them.

Comment: The questions are supposed to be of the "would this work" or "is this plausible" type, unless you specify the methods being used in the question there is no correct answer & you force anyone answering to first decide the methods for themselves, that's why what you've done is ask "how to" & there can be no right answer, the unspecified near future tech is especially egregious as everyone's going to have a different idea of a) what's possible b) how long away "near future" is, so it's completely opinion based.

Comment: @RonJohn I wouldn't have figured that was important here, since it's only the birth that is relevant to the question and not the rest of the offspring's development. If it's completely necessary for the question, the government takes the males to be raised in a military academy, and the females to be educated at performing homefront tasks such as factory work.

Comment: @Pelinore I see what you mean, and in that case I believe it might be best if I temporarily delete this question to try and fix it to fit into the parameters you specified.

Comment: "*I wouldn't have figured that was important here.  ...  the government takes the males to be raised in a military academy, and the females to be educated at performing homefront tasks such as factory work.*" LOL.  There won't be too many newborns marching drill or running machine tools.

Comment: Also, who's going to run the academies, if all the women are constantly pregnant?

Comment: @Sydney Sleeper : I'm only a few weeks old here myself so don't go too tightly by my opinion, check the help center resources (the question mark (?) top right) & what that says about questions.

Comment: Here's the problem with this question.  Either @RonJohn is right based on natural childbirth, or the answer is millions because the average woman is born with millions of eggs and futuretech is allowed to harvest them for test tubes.  Since the number can be anything between 34 and millions depending on unspecified tech, the answer is POB.  Frankly, if you need the people, you need to get the human out of the equation as quickly as possible.

Comment: @JBH *Brave New World* FTW!!!

Comment: I note that now that light weight assault rifles are common child soldiers are common in third world conflicts.  Thus the Evil Empire's cannon fodder do not have to be adults to carry guns.  I note that many evil users of teenage and child soldiers are equal opportunity and use many girl soldiers.

Comment: If the evil empire needs a lot more cannon fodder, why not increase production of robot soldiers in the factories?  War robots are a near future technology.  Inventing and building war robots is a lot easier than inventing and building parent surrogate robots, so the evil empire will not be able to raise, educate, and train nearly as many people as it could create with reproductive technology, unless it uses parental surrogate robots, in which case it should be able to crank out billions of war robots and not need to force the breeding of biological soldiers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More than basic math applies here. If you haven't heard of Octomom, she's a mother from a few years back who was pregnant with eight babies at once, so that's physically possible, but the mother would not likely come back from that to give more births. With IVF, you can at least get quadruplets with every pregnancy with relative safety assuming good hospitals. Introducing hormones to the mother's diet can start puberty earlier, even as early as 9 in some existing reported cases. Also, immediately after pregnancy, there is a bit of recovery involved, but within a few weeks the mother is hyper-fertile.

So the calculation is closer to 10 months from one birth to the next, starting at age 9. 45 is a good maximum age; after that you're much more likely to get children with down syndrome.

(45-9) years * 12 months per year / 10 months per pregnancy * 4 babies per pregnancy = **172.8 babies**. Yikes!

For reference, [the world record is currently 69](http://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/world-records/most-prolific-mother-ever).

Comment: "*(45-9) years * 12 months per year / 10 months per pregnancy * 4 babies per pregnancy = 172.8 babies.*  That's still basic math...

Comment: OP specified "*healthy children*", and a 9 year old won't be bearing too many healthy children.  Hips just aren't wide enough.

Comment: Well, basic math plus some basic biology.

Comment: I don’t have the scientific knowledge to prove it, but with near-future technology it may be possible to improve child-bearing capability at a younger age. Although now that you bring it up, it is not likely that quadruplets are going to work at such a young age. Perhaps the mother would need to start off with singles, and slowly move up from there as she ages.

Comment: Biology informs the math..  Your formula is nothing but a hyper-aggressive version of what I wrote in the comments.

Comment: Yes. Yes it is. I assumed that’s what OP was looking for.

Comment: Also note that with current / near-future technology a pregnancy doesn't really have to last the full 9 months - children born a couple of months early have a pretty good survival rate nowadays and with some surgery you can get them whenever you want.

Comment: Sorry to throw a wrench into your math, but you can use some of the baby girls to become a mom too, and produce more babies. I am pretty sure OP will run out of resources to feed all the children before he runs out of reproductive capacity of moms.

Comment: If you're looking for the potential for all women PLUS the exponential growth capability of their offspring, then yes, any given woman would have an infinite number of descendants, assuming an infinite number of resources and timespan.